# How can I see full process name using `ps ax -ocmd`?

Tags: awk, ps

I'm trying to `awk` by process name using `ps ax -ocmd`, but it only returns the first 27 characters for me.  Unfortunately this isn't enough to select (`awk`) the correct processes.

How can I find the whole process name?

```
> ps ax -ocmd
/bin/sh -c php /var/www/vho 27913       08:57
php /var/www/vhosts/path/to 27926       08:57
php /var/www/vhosts/path/to 31541    13:55:57
php /var/www/vhosts/path/to 31542    13:55:57
```

How can I find processes matching: `/var/www/vhosts/path/to/my/script.php`?

Ultimately I'm looking for processes matching `PROCESS_NAME` over 30 minutes old like so:

```
ps ax -ocmd,pid,etime | awk '/PROCESS_NAME/{split($(NF),a,":");if(a[1]>30)print}'
```

or

```
ps ax -ocmd,pid,etime | awk '/script.php/{split($(NF),a,":");if(a[1]>30)print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ps axww opid,etime,cmd`

From man:

> w      Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.

Although, when you use **awk** and `cmd` is the last column you don't even need `ww`.